# We need to refresh the page after logging in new user for the detail of new user in graphql otherwise it show the previous loggedin user's detail

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, graphql, apollo-client

I am creating quote app using react,graphql,apollo-client,mongodb atlas.
I am storing authentication token in the localStorage when user login and remove it when user logout.I have a profile page in which it shows the detail of loggedin user.

The issue is that when i logout and then login another user,it shows the detail of previous user and when i refresh the page then it shows the current user details.so, how can i get the new user's detail without refreshing the page?

CreateQuote component :

```
import { useMutation } from "@apollo/client";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { CREATE_QUOTE } from "../gqloperations/mutations";

function CreateQuote() {
  const [quote, setQuote] = useState("");
  const [createQuote, { loading, error, data }] = useMutation(CREATE_QUOTE, {
    refetchQueries: ["getAllQuotes", "getMyProfile"],
  });

  data && console.log(data);

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    createQuote({
      variables: {
        name: quote,
      },
    });
  };

  if (loading) {
    return <h1>loading...</h1>;
  }
  return (
    <div className="container">
      {error && <div className="red card-panel">{error.message}</div>}
      {data && <div className="green card-panel">{data.quote}</div>}
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={quote}
          onChange={(e) => setQuote(e.target.value)}
          placeholder="write your quote"
        />
        <button className="btn green" type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>
          create
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default CreateQuote;
```

Login Component :

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { LOGIN_USER } from "../gqloperations/mutations";

export default function Login() {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({ email: "", password: "" });
  const [signinUser, { loading, data, error }] = useMutation(LOGIN_USER, {
    refetchQueries: ["getMyProfile"],
    onCompleted(data) {
      localStorage.setItem("token", data.user.token);
      navigate("/");
    },
  });
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    signinUser({
      variables: {
        userSignin: formData,
      },
    });
    setFormData({ email: "", password: "" });
  };
  if (loading) return <h1>Loading</h1>;
  // if (data) {
  //   localStorage.setItem("token", data.user.token);
  //   navigate("/");
  // }
  return (
    <>
      {error && <div className="red card-panel">{error.message}</div>}
      {data && data.signupUser && (
        <div className="green card-panel">
          {data.user.token} login successfully
        </div>
      )}
      <div>
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <input
            type="email"
            name="email"
            value={formData.email}
            onChange={handleChange}
            placeholder="email"
          />
          <input
            type="password"
            name="password"
            value={formData.password}
            onChange={handleChange}
            placeholder="password"
          />
          <Link to="/login">
            <p>Don't have an account ?</p>
          </Link>
          <button type="submit" className="green btn">
            Login
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Profile component:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useQuery } from "@apollo/client";
import { GET_MY_PROFILE } from "../gqloperations/queries";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router";

export default function Profile() {
  const { loading, error, data, refetch } = useQuery(GET_MY_PROFILE);
  useEffect(() => {
    refetch();
  }, [data]);
  const navigate = useNavigate;
  if (!localStorage.getItem("token")) {
    navigate("/login");
  }
  if (loading) return <h1>Loading...</h1>;
  if (error) console.log(error);
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="center-align">
        <img
          style={{ border: "2px solid black", marginTop: "10px" }}
          className="circle"
          src={`https://robohash.org/${data.user.firstName}.png?size=200x200`}
          alt=""
        />
        <h5>
          {data.user.firstName} {data.user.lastname}
        </h5>
        <h5>Email-{data.user.email}</h5>
      </div>
      <h3>Your quotes</h3>
      {data.user.quotes.map((quote) => {
        return (
          <blockquote>
            <h6>{quote.name}</h6>
          </blockquote>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Navbar component: (contains Logout button)

```
import React from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

function NavBar() {
  const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  return (
    <div>
      <nav>
        <div className="nav-wrapper">
          <Link to="/" className="brand-logo left">
            Quotes
          </Link>
          <ul id="nav-mobile" className="right">
            {token ? (
              <>
                <li>
                  <Link to="/profile">Profile</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <Link to="/create">Create</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <button
                    className="red btn"
                    onClick={() => {
                      localStorage.removeItem("token");
                      navigate("/login");
                    }}
                  >
                    Logout
                  </button>
                </li>
              </>
            ) : (
              <>
                <li>
                  <Link to="/login">Login</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <Link to="/signup">Signup</Link>
                </li>
              </>
            )}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  );
}

export default NavBar;
```

**Edit :**
after slothOverlord's answer ,the updates are as below:
Navbar component

```
import React from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { client } from "../index.js";

function NavBar() {
  const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  return (
    <div>
      <nav>
        <div className="nav-wrapper">
          <Link to="/" className="brand-logo left">
            Quotes
          </Link>
          <ul id="nav-mobile" className="right">
            {token ? (
              <>
                <li>
                  <Link to="/profile">Profile</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <Link to="/create">Create</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <button
                    className="red btn"
                    onClick={async() => {
                      localStorage.removeItem("token");
                      await client.resetStore();
                      navigate("/login");
                    }}
                  >
                    Logout
                  </button>
                </li>
              </>
            ) : (
              <>
                <li>
                  <Link to="/login">Login</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <Link to="/signup">Signup</Link>
                </li>
              </>
            )}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  );
}

export default NavBar;
```

Login component :

```
import { useMutation } from "@apollo/client";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { LOGIN_USER } from "../gqloperations/mutations";

export default function Login() {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({ email: "", password: "" });
  const [signinUser, { loading, data, error ,client}] = useMutation(LOGIN_USER, {
    refetchQueries: ["getMyProfile"],
   
    onCompleted(data) {
      localStorage.setItem("token", data.user.token);
      client.clearStore();
      navigate("/");
    },
  });
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    signinUser({
      variables: {
        userSignin: formData,
      },
    });
    setFormData({ email: "", password: "" });
  };
  if (loading) return <h1>Loading</h1>;
  // if (data) {
  //   localStorage.setItem("token", data.user.token);
  //   navigate("/");
  // }
  return (
    <>
      {error && <div className="red card-panel">{error.message}</div>}
      {data && data.signupUser && (
        <div className="green card-panel">
          {data.user.token} login successfully
        </div>
      )}
      <div>
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <input
            type="email"
            name="email"
            value={formData.email}
            onChange={handleChange}
            placeholder="email"
          />
          <input
            type="password"
            name="password"
            value={formData.password}
            onChange={handleChange}
            placeholder="password"
          />
          <Link to="/login">
            <p>Don't have an account ?</p>
          </Link>
          <button type="submit" className="green btn">
            Login
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

other components are same as above.

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the store of apollo cache.
either use client.clearStore() /Reset the store
or client.resetStore() /Reset the store and Refetch any active queries

```
const [signinUser, { loading, data, error, client }] = useMutation(LOGIN_USER, {
    refetchQueries: ["getMyProfile"],
    onCompleted(data) {
      localStorage.setItem("token", data.user.token);
      client.clearStore //Make sure you reset it AFTER you are done adding/clearing tokens
      navigate("/");
    },
```

I also recommend you to use client.clearStore on your LOGOUT mutation, not on login.

Note that resetStore is async and you should await it.
More info at apollo docs: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/advanced-topics/

If you are using a normal function, you can import the cache from your Apollo cache (Where you exported it), and clear the store that way.

```
import {cache} from '../path/to/your/apollo/cache'

//...
           <button
                    className="red btn"
                    onClick={() => {
                      localStorage.removeItem("token");
                      client.resetStore()
                      navigate("/login");
                    }}
                  >
                    Logout
                  </button>
```

Comment: it's not working after doing this changes and why shoud we import cache? as we are only using client.

Comment: Can you update your question with the example of what you tried? You need to import it if you are using it outside the useMutation hook to call the method to clear the store.

Comment: i have updated the question,please have a look on the updates.

Comment: remove the client.resetStore() from your login mutation, That might be the issue as you delete the cache after you fetched them. You can also try to use fetchPolicy: 'network-only' in your login mutation options. This will force your query to skip cache checks and only fetch fresh data. Also note that you might not have cleared the user data correctly after logout, and your resetStore is still fetching new data with stale variables.  You can use "react-native-network-logger" to check if anything is called after you reset the store.

Comment: tried as you suggested, but still same thing is happening.

Comment: Oh, one more thing that you can try. Use a Contextprovider in your App.js to store your user data once logged in. Changing anything in your context provider will rerender every screen where you use your user data. Define a const [user, setUser] = useState() and then pass user and setUser to your context. When you log in or log out, use the setUser from your context and it will rerender just fine.

Comment: as per the requirement, i cannot use context , do you have any other solution?